# Analysis.. Convergence of sequence

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

I really struggle with understanding convergence and have the following questions..

> Determine whether the following sequences converge and if so, give the limit:
>
> 1. $x_n =  \bigg(\dfrac{7n+3}{2n+1}, \sqrt{\dfrac{{n+1}}{n}}\bigg)$     in         $(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_2)$
> 2. $x_n = \left(3+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}{,(-1)^n}+\dfrac{7}{n}\right)$ in $(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_2)$
> 3. $x_n(t)= \log\left(1+\dfrac{t}{n}\right) + \dfrac{nt^2}{1+nt}$ in $(C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$
>
> Hint for 3: $\log(1+x) \leq x$ for $x>0$

I don't really know where to even start,any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the second in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ? write the definition aof convergence than you should have point where to start

Comment: @DominicMichaelis No, the second is in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @Mathsstudent147 there are 2 , so maybe you made a typo

Comment: Your second sequence has $3$ coordinates. It is in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Unless you meant the second coordinate to be $(-1)^n7/n$ and made a typo?

Comment: @julien Yes i've just realised i did ake a typo.. it is meant to only be two coordiantes.. the second being $(-1)^n+\dfrac{7}{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Recall that if $f(n)=p(n)/q(n)$ is a rational fonction with numerator and denominator of same degree, then the limit at $+\infty$ exists and is the quotient of the leading coefficients. So 
 $$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{7n+3}{2n+1}=\frac{7}{2}\quad\mbox{and}\quad\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}=1.
$$
Now by continuity of the square root at $1$, the square root of the latter tends to $\sqrt{1}=1$.
So $x_n$ converges coordinatewise, which is equivalent to convergence in finite dimension. Hence
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}x_n=\left(\frac{7}{2},1\right).
$$

2) The second coordinate is $(-1)^n+7/n$. The subsequence of even indices is $1+7/(2n)$ and converges to $1$, while the subsequence of odd indices is $-1+7/(2n+1)$ and converges to $-1$. So this sequence does not converge. A fortiori $x_n$ does not converge.

3) This sequence of functions converges uniformly to
$$
x(t)=t
$$
on $[0,1]$.
To see this, compute $x_n(t)-t$ and simplify. You will find:
$$
x_n(t)-t=\log\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)-\frac{t}{1+nt}.
$$
Now 
$$
|x_n(t)-t|\leq |\log\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)|+\frac{t}{1+nt}\leq\frac{t}{n}+\frac{t}{nt}\leq \frac{2}{n}
$$
for all $t\in(0,1]$ first, and then of course for $t=0$. So
$$
\|x_n-x\|_\infty\leq \frac{2}{n}.
$$
Since the rhs tends to $0$, the squeeze theorem now shows that $x_n$ converges uniformly to $x$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: i've just realised i did make a typo.. it is meant to only be two coordiantes.. the second being $(-1)^n +\dfrac{7}{n}$

Comment: Fine, it does not change my answer. Do you understand it? Or do you need details?

Comment: No, thats great! You've explained it in a way i can really understand! Thanks

Comment: @Mathsstudent147 Ok, great then. You're welcome.